# Not getting the correct date from string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the date "30/06/2013" from the button:

I tried this code but I got in the log: 2013-01-04 22:00:00 +0000:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateBtn.titleLabel.text];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

and in the app i got this date "05/01/2013":

I also tried this code but it didn't work:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSTimeInterval interval = 5 * 60 * 60;
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateBtn.titleLabel.text];
date1 = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

It is important to note I use locale Hebrew.

Comment: try `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Apple's official documentation on date formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html). Please note how the format differs slightly across different platforms and versions.

Also note the difference between yyyy and YYYY.

Answer (score 2):

set date format to "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
    NSString *originalDate = @"30/06/2013";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:originalDate];
    NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

The explanation from @fzwo apple link

It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.